# Cyrus' Adventure (Part 5)

Tags: mathematics, computer-science

Cyrus walked through the third door and went into a damp passageway. Suddenly, Cyrus found a big bug on the floor. "Damn!" Cyrus stepped on it and the bug died. After a while, Cyrus arrived at a small room. Inside the room was a huge robot that wasn't working. Cyrus noticed a small hole on the robot. He tried putting the totem, and surprisingly, it fit. The robot started moving, and murmured something:

> 1-010-0-010-100-101-0-00

There was a number keyboard on the robot's belly. What should Cyrus type in?

---

Hints:

1

> decimal?

2

> 5-digit number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing hyphens gives:

> 1 | 0100 | 0101 | 0010 | 1000

which is

> Decimal: 83240
>  Hex:14528

As it's not the D then maybe the H?

Comment: You are correct! It is hex!

Answer (score 3):

The answer appears to be

> 12024500
>  
>  This is done by a direct binary-to-decimal conversion of each number between the dashes, as per the #computer tag, as well as the #decimal hint

Comment: It seems unlikely that that's the whole story, given e.g. that there's a 0 and a 00.

Comment: all too true. But getting the ball rolling first

Comment: @Kryesec You're close!

Comment: The hyphens doesn't mean anything. Since the robot was murmuring, it said things choppily.

Comment: Just Binary to Decimal gives 83240 ?

Comment: @Smock Close, but not the answer

Comment: Could you use the non-zero digits as the 5 digits needed?